# Is it Possible to get the degrees of Circle Image in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In Flutter I have rounded image of Map Check Picture Below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQc1E.png

So like that I am able to get any degree in picture and also draw something at that point.

If you know the solution of this problem then Please answer this question.

Comment: I think you are looking for `CustomPainter`

Comment: You can use pi. Please share more details about what you're trying to do

Comment: Hi Mohammad K. Albattikhi, Actually I want to create the qibla direction compass. So in which direction the qibla is I will create a pointer on that point on this map. I have direction of qibla just I want is to get the degrees of this picture so I am able to create pointer on that point. You said that you can use pi can you give more details . Thanks...

Comment: Hi Zilaid, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the widget by wrapping it with a `Transform.rotate` widget.

Here's an example:

```
Transform.rotate(
  angle: 45, //change this value to rotate the child
  child: Container(
  height: 100,
  width: 50,
  color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ),
```